# Typescript generic object propery const name get lost after map

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do it without "as"?

[Sandbox.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBtA5PHMANDDgEY4C6M8aoksA9AzAE7LwAm4ANgJ7YAieAOIDSAigCgovAA7IYAOSQLMM+SABmcFRCxgArolLIWVGExhCBMAD5XxkyXWjUWLDDpQQAdIniyABRgGAB8MADekjAxliEAlmhaMOrIAFxWwnYOAtExrMhQBiwhEfoUGTgQiFAAFjgAvpINAJROkgwAVNEAgu7w-Ikwyalp0VH52AAeGdAs8WAA5hUwcwuLANzRDVhS0QASIADuKSAw-gDWCvGwI3LpeRP5WFMwC0oqK2tLWzA7Up0GE4gA)

```
const names = ['a' , 'b'] as const // readonly ["a", "b"]
type Name = typeof names[number]  // "a" | "b"

const arr = names.map(n => {
    // n is of type: "a" | "b"
    return {[n]: 'smth'}
})


/*
 Array is of type:
 {
    [x: string]: string;
 }[]

 How to make it of type:
  {
    [x in Name]: string;
 }[]
*/
```